# How to get child element (itemHoverPhoto) from Image.Tooltip

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Image Stretch="UniformToFill" x:Name="itemPhoto" Width="120" Height="80" Source="/Resource/Image/gbricks.jpg">                                      
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Placement="Bottom">
            <ToolTip.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="30,0,30,0">
                        <Path Margin="34,0,0,0" Fill="#e5AAAAAA" Data="M 0 16 L 16 0 L 32 16 Z"/>
                        <Image x:Name="itemHoverPhoto" Height="500" Width="500" Source="/Resource/Image/gbricks.jpg"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToolTip.Template>
        </ToolTip>
    </Image.ToolTip>                                       
</Image>
```

How to get child element (itemHoverPhoto) from Image.Tooltip

Answer (score 0):

If you put this inside the `OnApplyTemplate()` of your window:

```
 ToolTip toolTip = this.itemPhoto.ToolTip as ToolTip;
 toolTip.ApplyTemplate();
 var itemHoverPhoto = toolTip.Template.FindName("itemHoverPhoto", toolTip);
```

then you have the itemHoverPhoto, and can manipulate it as you wish

Comment: Thank you - remember to mark my answer as a solution to your problem, if you find it so